# Print image name to console from UICollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I'm working with a UICollectionView where I have a UIImage with a Tap Gesture Recogniser as the cell model for my CollectionView.  I also have 57 images with different names that I want to print to the console depending on which image I tap on.

Here is my code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let OLLData = OLLCases()


    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



// MARK: - Navigation
@IBAction func isSelected(_ sender: Any) {
    print("selected \(caseName)")
}

}

//MARK: - Data source

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return OLLData.list.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell

    let image = OLLData.list[indexPath.item].image
    let caseName = OLLData.list[indexPath.item].image

    cell.label.text = caseName
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)



    return cell
}
}
```

I then have another swift file (PhotoCell )where I have the IBOutlets for label and imageView.

What methods are there of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to detect tap on image or the entire cell?

Comment: Preferably the image but it isn't too important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UICollectionViewDelegate` method to detect tap on cell but to use that first of all your `UICollectionView` need to confirm the `delegate` with your `UIViewController` like:

```
collectionView.delegate = self
```

in your `viewDidLoad` method.

then you need to replace

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

with

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
```

and use delegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

and you can get selected image name with

```
let caseName = OLLData.list[indexPath.item].image
print(caseName)
```

and `didSelectItemAt` will look like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let caseName = OLLData.list[indexPath.item].image
    print(caseName)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Your `extension` will look like:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return OLLData.list.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell

        let image = OLLData.list[indexPath.item].image
        let caseName = OLLData.list[indexPath.item].image

        cell.label.text = caseName
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)



        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let caseName = OLLData.list[indexPath.item].image
        print(caseName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused - do I put the didSelectItemAt at the same level as the numberOfItemsInSelection function?

Comment: Yes you need to put it with `numberOfItemsInSelection  `

Comment: Ok great thank you.  However I guess I need to remove the tap gesture recogniser for this to work?

Comment: Yes if tap on image is not important for you.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `didSelectItemAt` method, then get the cell you've selected like this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PhotoCell
    print(cell.imageView)
    print(cell.label)
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Add an extension for `UICollectionViewDelegate` below the last extension in your ViewController:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       print(OLLData.list[indexPath.item].image)
    }
}
```